# Encrypt string using public key as text in C#

Tags: c#, encryption, rsacryptoserviceprovider

I have recieved a public keY in txt format. (BEGIN CERTIFICATE---END CERTIFICATE)
I want to encrypt my message using this key in C# and send it across.

Similarly I have my private key in text format. I have shared my public key with the third party, which they are using to encrypt the message. I want to decrypt the message using my private key in TEXT format.
How do i do that in C#?

Kindly help.

Comment: You will need to discuss the details of your encryption scheme with the third party. There's no single possible option.

Comment: Please share your efforts, what you have done till now

Comment: Until now all I have done is search on the internet for options. i have realised that I can use RSACryptoServiceProvider. But all the examples show that the key is generated dynamically and then used. I am looking at ImportParameters method but am not able to make much of  headway.

Comment: Should I be converting the public key in some other format and then use it with RSACryptoServiceProvider?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyCrypto
{
    public X509Certificate2 GetDecryptionCertificate(string certificateName)
    {
        var my = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
        my.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        var collection = my.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, certificateName, false);
        if (collection.Count == 1)
        {
            return collection[0];
        }
        else if (collection.Count > 1)
        {
            throw new Exception(string.Format("More than one certificate with name '{0}' found in store LocalMachine/My.", certificateName));
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Certificate '{0}' not found in store LocalMachine/My.", certificateName));
        }
    }

    public X509Certificate2 GetEncryptionCertificate(string filePath)
    {
        var collection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
        collection.Import(filePath);
        return collection[0];

    }

    public string EncryptRsa(string input, X509Certificate2 x509Certificate2)
    {
        var output = string.Empty;

        using (RSA csp = (RSA)x509Certificate2.PublicKey.Key)
        {
            byte[] bytesData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
            byte[] bytesEncrypted = csp.Encrypt(bytesData, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA1);
            output = Convert.ToBase64String(bytesEncrypted);
        }
        return output;
    }

    public string DecryptRsa(string encrypted, X509Certificate2 x509Certificate2)
    {
        var text = string.Empty;

        using (RSA csp = (RSA)x509Certificate2.PrivateKey)
        {
            byte[] bytesEncrypted = Convert.FromBase64String(encrypted);
            byte[] bytesDecrypted = csp.Decrypt(bytesEncrypted, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA1);
            text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesDecrypted);
        }
        return text;
    }

 
}
```